# Prove $\sqrt{x(y-1)^2}$ if $x(y-1)^2\geq0$, $0$ if $x(y-1)^2<0$ is continuous in $R^2$

Tags: continuity

\begin{equation}
    f(x,y) = 
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{l l}
            \sqrt{x(y-1)^2}, \quad x(y-1)^2 \geq 0\\
            0, \quad x(y-1)^2 <0 \\
        \end{array}
        \right\}
\end{equation}

It is clear to me how to prove where $x(y-1)^2\neq0$, it is the border that is giving me some trouble.

I believe I was able to prove it is continuous when y=1, through the following:

$$
|\sqrt{x(y-1)^2}|=\sqrt{x(y-1)^2}=\sqrt{x}.|y-1|
$$

if $ \varepsilon \le 1 \implies 0 \leq \sqrt{x} \le \sqrt{a+1}  $

$$
\sqrt{x}.|y-1| \le \sqrt{a+1}.|y-1| \le \sqrt{a+1}.||(x-a),(y-1)||<\sqrt{a+1}.\varepsilon
$$

$$
\forall\delta>0,0<\varepsilon\le\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{a+1}}:||(x,y)-(a,1)||<\varepsilon \implies |f(x,y)-0|<\delta, a\in R^+_{0}
$$

I'm just not sure how to go about replicating this for when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,a), a \in R$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write this function as the composition of $(x,y)\to x(y-1)^2$ and $r(t)=\sqrt t$ if $t \geq 0$, $r(t)=0$ if $t<0$

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your answer. However, I am failling to understand how this helps me prove that the system is continuous in the entire set of Real numbers, could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: If $f$ and $r$ are continuous, then so is $r\circ f$.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, of course, that makes perfect sense, thank you. But I was looking for the classic definition of continuity, so I'll keep the thread open.

Comment: @Thomas: That looks like an answer.